# Request checksum from Amazon S3 in iOS

Tags: ios, rest, amazon-s3, upload, nsurlsession

I have developed an iOS application which can upload larger videos to an AWS S3 server.

I have integrated an MD5 checksum to my put request to in-order to validate after file uploaded to my AWS server.

```
 NSString *md5 = [FileHash md5HashOfFileAtPath:[url path]];

    NSMutableData *commandToSend= [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    unsigned char whole_byte;
    char byte_chars[3] = {'\0','\0','\0'};
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < [md5 length]/2; i++) {
        byte_chars[0] = [md5 characterAtIndex:i*2];
        byte_chars[1] = [md5 characterAtIndex:i*2+1];
        whole_byte = strtol(byte_chars, NULL, 16);
        [commandToSend appendBytes:&whole_byte length:1];
    }


    s3PutObjectRequest.cannedACL = [S3CannedACL publicRead];
        s3PutObjectRequest.endpoint = s3Client.endpoint;
        s3PutObjectRequest.contentType = fileMIMEType([url absoluteString]);
        
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",footage.footageId] forKey:@"x-amz-meta-footageId"];
        [dict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",footage.clipDuration]  forKey:@"x-amz-meta-duration"];
        s3PutObjectRequest.metadata =dict;
        [s3PutObjectRequest configureURLRequest];
         s3PutObjectRequest.contentMD5 = base64EncodedString;
     
        
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [s3Client signS3Request:s3PutObjectRequest];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request2 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:request.URL];
        [request2 setAllHTTPHeaderFields:[request allHTTPHeaderFields]];
        [request2 setValue:nil forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
       
    [request2 setValue:base64EncodedString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-MD5"];
```

I want to validate the checksum after the file has been uploaded to the server, and to do that I need to know how to get the checksum of the file after it's been uploaded.

Which object in the S3 REST API gives the checksum after file uploaded?

Comment: I removed the solution (*S3PutObjectResponse eTag function will give you the MD5 hash of the uploaded file*) and follow-up question from this post; solutions go in answers, and follow-up questions should be asked as separate questions. This post is not too broad/in need of focus, either; I'm guessing the reviewers were just hasty in trying to burninate the [tag:amazon] tag. I have voted to reopen.