# How to set up a hex data with time info in it in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, hex, bluetooth-lowenergy, nsdata

In my `BLE` project, I will write a `hex data` which include time in it.

The `hex data` is like this below:

`<160922162300>` , what mean `2016 - 09 - 22 - 16:23:00`

I use the function to write the `data` to my `BLE develop board`:

`[weakSelf.currPeripheral writeValue:myData forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite];`

and the `myData` content is `<160922162300>`

How can I get the content is the certain info `hex data`?

Comment: Use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305225/best-way-to-serialize-an-nsdata-into-a-hexadeximal-string to transform `yourCharacteristic.value` (which is a `NSData`) into `NSString`, then use `NSDateFormatter` with `yyMMddHHmmss` for the `dateFormat` and you'll get the corresponding `NSDate`. For the reverse, you can also use the `NSDateFormatter` to transform the `NSDate` into `NSString` and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317860/converting-hex-nsstring-to-nsdata to transform it into the wanted `NSData` object.

Comment: @Larme Your answer is so well.