# NSString to NSData without encoding

Tags: objective-c

What is reverse code for:

```
NSString *token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tokenData];
```

So far I tried:

```
NSString *tokenStr = @"<e307808e 2e443d7d ef35f248 aafc5e97 fb8e1cba d65d8ac1 88441028 3bd7b383>";
NSData * tokenData = [tokenStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *origToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tokenData];
```

However `token` != `origToken`

**I cannot change:**

```
NSString *token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tokenData];
```

because I write Unit test for this code

Comment: The "reverse" (which is not really a reverse, but): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317860/converting-hex-nsstring-to-nsdata

Comment: @Larme yes, I found solution, tnx: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35334124/1631379

Answer (score 0):

%@ format specifier is equivalent to invoking `description` method.

Its output is ["A string that contains a hexadecimal representation of the object’s contents in a property list format."](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1412579-description?language=objc)

How about testing as below?

```
NSString *token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tokenData];
NSString *tokenDesc = [tokenData description];

ASSERT([token isEqualToString:tokenDesc]);
```